# Capturar el hostname y la ip sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Es posible capturar la ip y el hostname de un equipo en especifico en sql?, esto para el tema de logs, llevar la trazabilidad de quien ejecuta que y poder saber desde donde se ejecuta exactamente

Answer (score 2):

Se puede capturar mediante esta consulta

```
select HOST_NAME() hostanme, client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

seria que lo pongas dentro de tu codigo para el log, sea en un trigger o como lo estes manejando, este el resultado que devuelve, ya solo es que lo captures en variables y lo guardes en tu tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]